# Returning a value from firestore snapshot

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So I have this function:

```
export const getLastMsg = (user, convoid) => {
  let item = []
   user &&  db.collection('chats').doc(convoid).collection('messages').orderBy('date', 'desc').limit(1).onSnapshot(snap=> {
    let items = []
    snap.forEach(doc => items.push(doc.data())) 
    item = items[0]
  }) 
}
```

When I call this function in my app, i get undefined, but when i console log the value inside the snapshot i get the value. Any Idea how I can make this function return the value?

Comment: I think the answer is right in the question

Comment: Not possible unless you make the function async and return a promise that resolves to the value you want the caller to receive.  Also you should not use onSnapshot if you want to return a single value.  onSnapshot sets up a persistent listener that yields document changes over time as they change.

Comment: How do you call the `getLastMsg`? If possible, could you please include a reproducible code in which shows that you're getting the undefined value. Also, do you really intend to use `onSnapshot` (listen to the realtime changes) or do you just want to fetch the data once?

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning item in getLastMsg() - it's always going to return undefined.

Comment: when i put the return, i get undefined

Comment: The function getting the messages is asynchronous. You need to use async/await.